# Correctly escape awk command in tmux window-status-format

Tags: awk, zsh, tmux

I want each window status to include information about the current pane directory but I want to trim it a bit using awk. I'm using tmux v1.8 and using zsh as my shell.

I tried the following (and every sort of escaping I can think of) but it doesn't work.

```
set -g window-status-format "#(echo '#{pane_current_path}' | awk -F 'Documents/' '{print $2}')"
```

Could someone help me correctly escape this so that this command works? Thanks!

Comment: where is this cmd string being executed from, or what `.cfg` file (or similar) is it included in? All shells already have a cmd `set`, Don't you have to "send" the cmd to `tmux`? I don't see that happening here. Just a 2nd set of eyes, not a tmux user (obviously). Good luck.

Comment: This is within the ~/.tmux.conf file that tmux uses to configure itself.

Comment: This works on tmux v2.5

Comment: What happend? Could you describe the expected result?

Comment: It seems like this didn't work in v1.8 but it did work in v2.5. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

We could escape dollar signs in the `#(shell-command)` form.
So, `$2` could be escaped with `\$2` like this:

```
set -g window-status-format "#(echo '#{pane_current_path}' | awk -F 'Documents/' '{print \$2}')"
```

Comment: How about issuing the command `mkdir -p /tmp/Documents/test && cd /tmp/Documents/test` and watcihng the result? The field separator for the `awk` command is `Documents/`, so I assume that it is intended to see the empty result in the window statuses if there are not any `Documents/`s in the `#{pane_current_path}`.